# Error: $injector:modulerr AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know this subject has been posted a lot but none of the solutions seem to be specific to my problem. I'm getting an error on the line that begins with ".service". In the inspector it just says, "unexpected token ." as if it didn't like the period. After that line it has the $injector:modulerr error. Any suggestions? (I didn't include the json file because it's just an array of objects).

**JS**

```
angular.module("powerpotApp", [])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {

    dataService.getPlants(function(response) {
        $scope.plants = response.data;
    });
});

.service('dataService', function($http) {

    this.getPlants = function(callback) {
        $http.get('mock/plants.json').then(callback)
    }
});
```

Comment: Delete the semi-colon before the period. Or use getter: `angular.module("powerpotApp").service('dataService',...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put a semi colon at your controller so it is a javascript syntax error.

It should be like this:

```
angular.module("powerpotApp", [])

.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {

    dataService.getPlants(function(response) {
        $scope.plants = response.data;
    });
})   // removed semi colon here

.service('dataService', function($http) {

    this.getPlants = function(callback) {
        $http.get('mock/plants.json').then(callback)
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.